# PostgreSQL queries not killed on app server shutdown

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, wildfly, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

I have a WildFly which hosts an app which is calling some long running SQL queries (say queries or SP calls which take 10-20 mins or more).

Previously this WildFly was pointing to SQL Server 2008, now to Postgres 11.

Previously when I killed/rebooted WildFly, I had noticed that pretty quickly (if not instantaneously) **the long-running SP/query calls that were triggered from the Java code (running in WildFly) were being killed too**.

Now... with Postgres I noticed that these long running queries remain there and keep running in Postgres even after the app server has been shut down.

What is causing this? Who was killing them in SQL Server (the server-side itself or the JDBC driver or ...)? Is there some setting/parameter in Postgres which controls this behavior i.e. what the DB server will do with the query provided that the client who triggered the query has been shut down.

EDIT: We do a graceful WildFly shutdown by sending a command to WF to shutdown itself. Still the behavior seems different between SQL Server and Postgres.

Comment: From the [JDBC Connection doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()) : "If the close method is called and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined". My guess is that the SQLServer JDBC driver choses to abort the transaction, possibly to be coherent with the [.Net implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close?view=netframework-4.8) which does, while the postgreSQL JDBC driver doesn't

Comment: Hmm, according to [this DBA SE answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81424) PostgreSQL should interrupt queries once the connection that initiated them gets closed, but it might not realise it while it's processing.

Comment: So possibly the PG JDBC driver is causing the issue, right? Is there any setting in the PG driver maybe? Or in the Postgres server itself? I cannot imagine this behavior is just like this and cannot be changed.

Comment: That's where I was going with my first comment yeah, but given the link in the second It seems more likely to me that PostgreSQL is busy processing and doesn't check whether it should abort the query until later. I've checked the JDBC driver parameters anyway but there's nothing related.

Comment: You could make sure the problem has nothing to do with Wildfly & the JDBC driver by testing with a command line client (`pgsql` if memory serves right) whose connection you'd interrupt in one or more ways described in the DBA SE answer. If it behaves the same you'll have to change either the query or the postgreSQL DB configuration (not that I know any that could affect this behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

If shutting down the application server causes JDBC calls that terminate the database session, this should not happen. If it doesn't close the JDBC connection properly, I'd call that a bug in the application server. If it does, but the queries on the backend are not canceled, I'd call that a bug in the JDBC driver.

Anyway, a workaround is to set [`tcp_keepalives_idle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) to a low value so that the server detects dead TCP connections quickly and terminates the query.

Comment: Laurenz, thanks very much for your answer. I have a few additional questions. 1) Quote: "If shutting down the application server causes JDBC calls that terminate the database session, this should not happen" I don't understand what you mean here. Just the opposite is true, no? I mean the action of shutting down the app server should sooner or later lead to closing the DB sessions from that server to the DB server (as far I understand it's the DB server's responsibility to detect and close lingering sessions and that's what tcp_keepalives_idle is about, correct?).

Comment: 2) I checked the docs on tcp_keepalives_idle so thanks for pointing us to this option. It is set to 300 in our case (which is OK, I think). But... is it possible the DB side is not respecting this value? I had definitely seen queries being executed on the server side, even after 300 secs of inactivity from the client side (say because an app server was shut down or because an end web user closed the page which issued the query/func call).

Comment: Ad 1) Yes, something is obviously wrong. I wanted to express that I am not sure what; is it a) the application server that does not close the session or b) that you don't shut down the application server cleanly or c) a bug in the JDBC driver. Ad 2) if you set `tcp_keepalives_idle` to 5 minutes on the server (and reload!), it should definitely cancel long running queries after 5 minutes (+ some grace time) once the client socket is gone. Anything else would be a PostgreSQL bug.