# PostgreSQL - tcp_keepalives_idle - explanation needed

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

I am reading the PostgreSQL docs on this parameter tcp_keepalives_idle.

> tcp_keepalives_idle (integer)
>
> Specifies the number of seconds of inactivity after which TCP should send a keepalive message to the client. A value of 0 uses the system default. This parameter is supported only on systems that support TCP_KEEPIDLE or an equivalent socket option, and on Windows; on other systems, it must be zero. In sessions connected via a Unix-domain socket, this parameter is ignored and always reads as zero.

Questions:

1) What does that TCP_KEEPIDLE exactly mean? I find it in some Linux man pages but don't quite understand it. Which systems support TCP_KEEPIDLE and which not?

2) What does "sessions connected via a Unix-domain socket" mean? I have PostgreSQL server in AWS (RDS) and sessions connect to it from various OSs
(Windows, Linux, etc.). So... what does that socket thing mean?

Note that this question is related to my other question here

[PostgreSQL queries not killed on app server shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972569/postgresql-queries-not-killed-on-app-server-shutdown)

in which I got some suggestions to look at and try to use tcp_keepalives_idle.

So... `tcp_keepalives_idle` is set to 300 (secs) in my system, but some queries continue to run even for a longer time after the client who initiated them has been killed (shut down). And I am still trying to find a way to prevent this.

Comment: Could you share anything you have found if there is any?

Comment: @JeongKim I don't think we ever solved this. I think at the end, we just implemented some cron job to run periodically (say every 20 mins) an SQL function/procedure which detects and kills these "hanging queries".